# Partially resolve/follow symlinks when globbing in zsh/Bash

Tags: bash, zsh, symlink, wildcards

Assume I have a file `a` which is a symlink to `b`, which in turn is a symlink to `c`.

With zsh's `:A` modifier, globbing a will result in an absolute path, resolving all symlinks, hence `a(:A)` will expand to the absolute path of `c` (on systems that have the `realpath` library).

Is it possible to get `b` (absolute or relative, but directly as a result of the globbing, not for example by looking at the output of `ls -l`) or even files up to arbitrary symlink depths?

A solution for Bash would also be interesting to know about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always create a function to be used with the `+` glob qualifier:

```
$ zmodload zsh/stat
$ resolve() { [[ -L $REPLY ]] && stat -A REPLY +link -- ${1-$REPLY}; }
$ print -r - a(+resolve)
b
$ print -r - a(+resolve:a)
/home/stephane/b (though see caveat below)
```

Note that if you do `a(+resolve+resolve)`, the second `resolve` will still be called on the original filename (`a`), not on the result of the first `resolve` (`b`). You could however do:

```
$ print -r - a(e['resolve && resolve'])
c
```

to chain the two `resolve`s. However (and the caveat also applies to the usage of `:a` above), although it will work for this particular example, that's not a valid thing to do in the general case, as targets of symlinks, when relative paths, are relative to the parent of the symlink, not the current working directory, so if `dir/link` points to `foo`, that's the `dir/foo` file, not `foo`, so it's only valid when resolving symlinks in the current working directory.

That would stop being a problem though if we change our `resolve` so it computes a full path of the target of the symlink:

```
resolve() {
  local target
  [[ -L $REPLY ]] &&
    stat -A target +link -- ${1-$REPLY} &&
    case $target in
      (/*) REPLY=$target;;
      (*) REPLY=${REPLY:h:a}/$target;;
    esac
}
```

`bash` has no glob qualifier, nor any interface to `readlink()` (like `zsh`'s `stat` builtin), but on some systems, you'll find a `readlink` command:

```
$ readlink a
b
```

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks!